# Are there analytic philosophers of difference?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, contemporary-philosophy, difference

I've gathered from the IEP article on [Differential Ontology](https://www.iep.utm.edu/diff-ont/) that Gilles Deleuze wrote about difference in the sense that I'm interested in but not in a way that I'm interested in. I would like to see more analysis and contextualization of difference *per se*, especially within ontology, but in a much less "continental" format.

Comment: Not really, there are too many fundamental methodological and cultural differences between the respective traditions. But DeLanda, who lives in the US, wrote an exposition of Deleuze's ontology aimed more at the Anglophone audience that few analytic philosophers who take interest in Deleuze find more readable. See [Protevi's critical review](http://www.protevi.com/john/web_DeLanda_ISVP_review.pdf) of his Intensive Science & Virtual Philosophy. You may also find [Bell's essay Deleuze and Analytic Philosophy](https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/jbell/deleuzeandanalytic.doc) useful.

Comment: Thanks, that stuff looks interesting. To clarify though, what I'm looking for is analytic philosophers focusing on difference itself, not responding to Deleuze.

Comment: I do not think that exists, at least not that they would express themselves in such terms. Loose parallels between Derrida/Deleuze and Quine/Davidson/Rorty are often drawn, but not exactly on ontology, and it would be a big stretch to call the latter "philosophers of difference". You would have to be much more specific on "difference in the sense that I'm interested" to tell if they are relevant, such transpositions do not come without a great deal of violence to both sides.